# Android: How to render emojis from a text file using Android TextView?

Tags: java, android, emoji

I have a text file with over 2000 emojis in it from Emoji 5.0. My program selects one line from the file, then returns the line as a string. Code for that:

```
   public String getLine() throws IOException{
    AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
    //String[] files = assetManager.list("");
    InputStream input = null;

    try{
        input = assetManager.open("words/words.txt");
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Oops, something when wrong");
    }
    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(max- min + 1) + min;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    for(int j = 1; j < i1; ++j)
        br.readLine();
    final String lineIWant;
    lineIWant = br.readLine();
    return lineIWant;
}
```

This string is then placed in a TextView:

```
Button Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);  
TextView ViewWord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GenWord);  
final TextView finalViewWord = ViewWord;
final String[] Word = {null};

Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                //get the word
                Word[0] = getLine();

                //set the word
                finalViewWord.setText(Word[0]);   
                //to keep Cody happy
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

However, when it is attempted to be rendered I get this:

[image: Weird text in the TextView]

What I want is to display the system default emojis in the TextView, I do not wish to use emojicon. If you need the file with all the emojis then I will be happy to provide it.

EDIT: Here's the error I'm getting:

```
08-05 18:26:14.671 17177-17253/com.ghostcode.emojio W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (4098x3660, max=4096x4096)
```

Here's some sample emojis:

☠️

Comment: Are your emojis Unicode emojis?

Comment: Oh, just went back to check the file and there's something up: Ŋ☄️
☀️
ߌĊ⛅️
ߌŊߌƊߌȊ☁️
ߌǊ⛈
ߌɊߌȊ☃️
⛄️

Comment: Replaced the emojis and that did not fix it

Comment: Can you add a sample of couple of emojis in your question

Comment: Aye no bother will update now

Comment: Can you try adding just one emoji instead of entire line. Your emoji size shouldn't be this large